# Blender won't open - Sketchfab addon killed it

Tags: add-on, error

I just added the Sketchfab addon, which seemed to work fine. But now when I try to open Blender 3.0 (on my M1 Macbook) it just hangs, with "Application not Responding". Rebooting makes no difference. The Sketchfab addon has killed it dead.

I tried to get round it by downloading the latest version of Blender. That opened fine. I then tried to import my settings from 3.0, but it caused 3.3 to hang. Now that won't open either!

I then deleted Blender 3.3 from my system and reinstalled it. It still won't open!

How do I retrieve Blender 3.3? And is there any way of importing my settings from the broken 3.0 version? The oldest version I have of Blender is 3.0 so I can't import from an earlier version. Has anyone else experienced the Sketchfab addon doing this? I can't believe there were no warnings about this on the Sketchfab website.

***Update***
I have managed to fix 3.3 but not 3.0. I opened Blender from the Mac Terminal and this is what I get during the no response:

```
/Applications/Blender\ 3.3.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender ; exit;
system@Systems-MBP ~ % /Applications/Blender\ 3.3.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender ; exit;
Read prefs: /Users/system/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.3/config/userpref.blend
Reloading external rigs...
Reloading external metarigs...
The custom presets directory seems invalid: /Remap Presets/
```

I opened the Blender 3.3 directory in the Library and located the default startup.blend file and the userpref.blend file and deleted them both.

Now 3.3 opens. But does this mean the settings preferences of 3.0 is corrupted beyond all repair?